# Timestamp Query returns nothing in fireStore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have `timestamp` field in Firestore.

This is stored with `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` when I save this field.

[image]

I check this timestamp prints result:

`Timestamp(seconds=1676893243, nanoseconds=682000000)`

I get fireStore data with timestamp query like the below code.

```
val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

        // diary
        db.collection("diary")
            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("timestamp", simpleDateFormat.parse(thisWeekStart).time)
            .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("timestamp", simpleDateFormat.parse(thisWeekEnd).time)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { diaryDocuments ->
                Log.d("랭킹결과30", "${diaryDocuments.size()}")

                for (diaryDocument in diaryDocuments) {
                    var userId = diaryDocument.data.getValue("userId").toString()
                    var timestamp = diaryDocument.data.getValue("timestamp").toString()

                    ....
```

However, this result is nothing.

`thisWeekStart` is "2023-02-20" and `thisWeekEnd` is "2023-02-26".

`simpleDateFormat.parse(thisWeekStart).time` prints **1676818800000**, and `simpleDateFormat.parse(thisWeekEnd).time` prints **1677337200000**.

So data having **1676893243** should be printed, but nothing comes.

How can I query timestamps in a proper way?

---

According to @AlexMamo's advice, I create `Date()` from with below.

```
val startDate = LocalDate.of(
            thisWeekStart.substring(0, 4).toInt(),
            thisWeekStart.substring(5, 7).toInt(),
            thisWeekStart.substring(8, 10).toInt()
        )
        val endDate = LocalDate.of(
            thisWeekEnd.substring(0, 4).toInt(),
            thisWeekEnd.substring(5, 7).toInt(),
            thisWeekEnd.substring(8, 10).toInt()
        )
```

And I check this prints **2023-02-20**, **2023-02-20** each.

And I put query.

```
        .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("timestamp", startDate)
        .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("timestamp", endDate)
```

But it prints error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Found conflicting getters for name getChronology on class java.time.LocalDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `simpleDateFormat.parse(thisWeekStart).time` prints 1676818800000, it means that you're using inside your query a number, which is not correct since your `timestamp` field holds a Firestore Timestamp and not a long value.

To solve this, you have to pass to the `whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo()` and `whereLessThanOrEqualTo()`, [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects that represent "2023-02-20" and "2023-.02-26"

Comment: I tried but it throws error. I add that part on my post, can you check?

Comment: No, you should create [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects, **not** LocalDate.

Comment: Hey Hyejung. Can I help you with other information regarding this question?

Comment: No, I was asking something different. Do you need any other information, besides what I have already provided? Is there everything clear now?